# Why are the durations of tasks belong to the same job are quite different in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Look at the picture below, these 24 tasks belong to a same job and 
the amount of data to be processed for each task is basically the same and time used to gc is very short, my question is why are the durations of tasks belong to the same job are so different?

[image]

Comment: Without looking at the code is not possible to say, and then there's network and disk access in the picture.Or could have a `Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(72000))` in the job, for all I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try and check **Event Timeline** for tasks in your spark UI. Check why slow task are running slow.

Are they taking more time in serialization/deserialization?

Is it because of scheduler delay?

or the executor computation time?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, do you know how can I see a particular task's time cost to do these ?

Comment: sorry i could not figure out what actually you are trying to ask? you are asking how to get to above screen? or how to understand above graph?

Comment: Thank you, i understand it now. Usually, more shuffle data will cost more time ?